# ARKit 1.5 – Vertical objects detection

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I use ARKit 1.5 and this func to highlight vertical surfaces, but it doesn't work really well.

```
func createPlaneNode(planeAnchor: ARPlaneAnchor) -> SCNNode {
    let scenePlaneGeometry = ARSCNPlaneGeometry(device: metalDevice!)
    scenePlaneGeometry?.update(from: planeAnchor.geometry)
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: scenePlaneGeometry)
    planeNode.name = "\(currPlaneId)"
    planeNode.opacity = 0.25

    if planeAnchor.alignment == .vertical {
        planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    }
    currPlaneId += 1
    return planeNode
}
```

It always finds some FeaturePoints on vertical objects but very rare it actually highlights the surface using the planeNode that I created.

I want to be able to detect and highlight things like a pillar or even a man. How would you approach this?
[Image of object with featurePoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWvXw.jpg)
[Image with the result in best case scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjj4T.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In ARKit 1.5 and ARKit 2.0 there's **`.planeDetection`** instance property allowing you to enable `.horizontal`, `.vertical`, or both simultaneously `.horizontal and .vertical` detections.

```
var planeDetection: ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.PlaneDetection { get set }
```

ViewController's code:

```
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
configuration.planeDetection = .vertical
//configuration.planeDetection = [.vertical, .horizontal]
sceneView.session.run(configuration)
```

If you want to successfully detect and track vertical objects in your environment, you need good lighting conditions and rich non-repetitive texture. Look at the picture below:

[image]